# Show thumbnails and select the cover photo

Tags: c#, asp.net

We need to display all the thumbnails in one folder (e.g. c:/photos/101/tn/ folder) and then select one image as cover photo. Once the editor clicks on the "Set Cover Image" button, grab the select photo ID. Once the id is grabbed, I will store the info in the database.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem (other than posting this question here which doesn't count :-))?

Comment: Hello, I started looking into the File IO stuff, but don't have any written code yet.

Answer (score 1):

Well, You don't expect to see a working code in the answers here do you? I takes some time and effort to write such a code. 
No offense but people are here to show you the way or help you overcome the problems that you face when you're writing the code. Not getting your work done.
Actually, I did such a thing on YAF project. (http://www.yetanotherforum.net)
So to see a working example, You can download the source and see the YAF Albums code. Although I generated the thumbnails programmatically there, but that could be changed easily if you want to.

Comment: I am not expecting the full working code for the project :) I just wanted to know how to show thumbnails from a folder and select one of them. Thought it is few lines of code. Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see. Then take a look at http://forums.asp.net/t/1110308.aspx Also, There a quick way of doing this at http://asp.syantien.com/pgeArticle.aspx?AID=43 but you should handle some click events to extract the photoID